# Шаблон для регулярки из цифр и одного дефиса

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужен шаблон для регулярного выражения, который ищет в списке номера из любого количества цифр и ровно одного дефиса в любом месте. Попробовала вот такое, но оно не работает

```
for i in list:
    reg = re.findall(r'\d+-{1}\d+', i)
```

Comment: `\d*-\d+|\d+-\d*`

Comment: Здравствуйте, ваше выражение почему-то захватывает '02-9374-2389', '0996-4258554', '(47) 5032-8079'

Comment: Ну, вы же в примере хотели `re.findall`. Оно и нашло соответствующую подстроку. И чем вам не подходит 2 и 3? Там же ровно один дефис и вокруг цифры. Хотите, чтобы соответствовало всей строке - используйте `re.fullmatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такую регулярку:

```
^\d+-\d+$
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/9URpsS/1).

**Объяснение:**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d+` - последовательность цифр в количестве от одной до бесконечности
- `-` - символ дефиса
- `$` - конец строки